# Can't parse HTML in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I use this {{job.description}}, I get this as output:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;Core Responsibilities&lt;/span&gt; :&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Service level assurance&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Resolution of all franchise related issues&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Engage with the franchise through weekly meetings, proactive emails, and newsletters&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Franchise management&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Drive franchise business growth&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;CSAT Target achievement and delivery of actions to improve service&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Ongoing Feedback and VOC on process improvement.&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Escalation analysis and improvements&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Increase customer satisfaction by understanding business needs and providing additional solutions and resources.&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;O0&quot;&gt;&amp;bull;Work with customers to establish critical goals, or other key performance indicators and aid the customer in achieving their goals.&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;Qualifications&lt;/span&gt; :&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Education : &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;Graduate&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Years of experience : 2-3&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Professional attributes :&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;Needs proactiveness and anticipation to understand customers&#039; problems.&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;Adaptability to customer&amp;rsquo;s need and requirement.&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;Should be a problem solver&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Personal attributes :&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;We are looking for go-getters, with high drive and ownership.&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;div&gt;&amp;bull;Candidate should have good communication and listening skills&lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Locations:&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Gurgaon&lt;/p&gt;
```

So I tried with `$sce` filter as recommended by many here:

```
myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="job.description | unsafe"></div>
```

And now the output is as follows:

```
<p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Core Responsibilities</span> :</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <div class="O0">&bull;Service level assurance</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Resolution of all franchise related issues</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Engage with the franchise through weekly meetings, proactive emails, and newsletters</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Franchise management</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Drive franchise business growth</div> <div>&bull;CSAT Target achievement and delivery of actions to improve service</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Ongoing Feedback and VOC on process improvement.</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Escalation analysis and improvements</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Increase customer satisfaction by understanding business needs and providing additional solutions and resources.</div> <div class="O0">&bull;Work with customers to establish critical goals, or other key performance indicators and aid the customer in achieving their goals.</div> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Qualifications</span> :</p> <p>Education : &nbsp;</p> <div>&bull;Graduate&nbsp;</div> <p>Years of experience : 2-3</p> <p>Professional attributes :</p> <div>&bull;Needs proactiveness and anticipation to understand customers' problems.</div> <div>&bull;Adaptability to customer&rsquo;s need and requirement.</div> <div>&bull;Should be a problem solver</div> <p>Personal attributes :</p> <div>&bull;We are looking for go-getters, with high drive and ownership.</div> <div>&bull;Candidate should have good communication and listening skills</div> <p>Locations:</p> <p>Gurgaon</p>
```

It did parsed the HTML but on a whole new level! Any idea where I'm going wrong? I have tried the ngSanitize too and had the same issue. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: So, what's wrong? What do you mean by "*on a whole new level*"? It seems correctly parsed to me...

Comment: Ummm No! HTML code shouldn't be shown to the user.

Comment: Oh, you're saying that what you posted on the output is what the user sees? Your HTML are stored on database like the first output provided, right?

Comment: If this is the case, seems like you want "two parse rounds", as your HTML is in string format and you want it to be interpreted by the browser. Did you consider the option of storing it on database on plain format instead of storing it converted to string?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't have access to the database. I just got the APIs.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done and can't test it now... But can you try applying the filter twice? Or applying `ngSanitize` twice?